# Properties of Hausdorff $s$-dimensional outer measure

Tags: measure-theory

I have some difficulties on proving results using the definitions of measures. This one is on Hausdorff outer measure. I need to prove the following intuitive result:

> Consider $s\geq 1$ and $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ a Borel set. Show that if $\mathbb{H}_s^*(A)<\infty$ and $r>s$, then $\mathbb{H}_r^*(A)=0$.

Any suggestions on how to start would be appreciated. Is it better to work with properties of infimum or properties of the sums? The definitions are:

$$\mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A)=\inf\left\{\sum_{k\geq 1}(\operatorname{diam}(A_k))^s:A\subset\bigcup_k A_k, \operatorname{diam}(A_k)<\delta\right\}$$

and

$$\mathbb{H}_s^*(A)=\lim_{\delta\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A)=\sup_{\delta>0}\mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A).$$

I know that since $\operatorname{diam}(A_k)\rightarrow 0$, I have $\operatorname{diam}(A_k)^r<\operatorname{diam}(A_k)^s$, and then

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}(\operatorname{diam}(A_k))^r\leq\sum_{k\geq 1}(\operatorname{diam}(A_k))^s.$$

Taking infimum on both sides the inequality holds. And now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That inequality would not help, I think.
We need to use the fact that $r-s>0$ and hence $\delta^{r-s}$ goes to $0$ as $\delta$ goes to $0$. Here is a proof.

Let $A \subset \bigcup_k A_k$, where $\operatorname{diam}(A_k)< \delta$ and $\sum_k \operatorname{diam}(A_k)^s \leq \mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A) + 1$. We can do that since, by definition, $\mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A)$ is the infimum of such quantities.
Then
$$
\mathbb{H}_{r,\delta}^*(A) \leq \sum_k \operatorname{diam}(A_k)^r \leq \delta^{r-s} \sum_k \operatorname{diam}(A_k)^s \leq \delta^{r-s} \left(\mathbb{H}_{s,\delta}^*(A) + 1\right).
$$

By letting $\delta$ go to $0$ we get the result.

Comment: I edited your answer, I think I get the idea. Why does the second inequality hold?

Comment: Yes, thank you for that, I forgot the parenthesis! 
$\operatorname{diam}(A_k)^r=\operatorname{diam}(A_k)^{r-s}\operatorname{diam}(A_k)^s$ and $\operatorname{diam}(A_k) \leq \delta$ for every $k$.

Comment: of course, thank you very much!